How to generate arrival time following Poisson distribution?
I am simulating the agents arrival in the system. I need the time stamp of  their arrival.
I have 500 arrivals in a day. I wrote this function:
def random_time():
    hour=rd.randint(0,23)
    minute=rd.randint(0,59)
    second=rd.randint(0,59)
    return dt.time(hour, minute, second)

But I want the simulation to  follow a Poisson distribution (preferrably using Simpy) .  How to  do that?
Any help would  be appreciated.
